# How to check id of textbox in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this great JavaScript that automatically populates the values of all textboxes on a page with a number, starting at 1 then increasing.

```
 function editTextBoxes() {
        var textboxs = $('input:text');
       
        for (i = 0; i <= textboxs.length; i++) {
            $('input:text:eq(' + i + ')').val(i + 1);
        }
    }
```

However, I only want to fill textboxes who's id **contain** `txtSortOrder`.

Can someone please help me fix this line: (it's just a guess)

```
if ($('input:text:eq(' + i + ')').ID.Contains("txtSortOrder")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull any attribute using the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function. For the `Contains()`, you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) which will return `-1` if the search is not found.

So that brings us this far:

```
if ($('input:text:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id').indexOf("txtSortOrder") !== -1)
```

Now, for your iteration, you can actually use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to process the results of your query.

E.g.

```
function editTextBoxes() {
    $('input:text[id~=txtSortOrder]').each(function (index) {
        $(this).val(index + 1);
    });
}
```

Notice this extends your selector to use [Attribute Contains word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/): `input:text[id~=txtSortOrder]`

Which means you do not have to do the ID comparison manually

Comment: Ah, no it's not equals txtSortOrder, but just contains it.

Comment: @aron - oops, you're right. :) It would be `~=` rather than `!=` - see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
function editTextBoxes() {
    // it will select all textboxes which id contain txtSortOrder
    var textboxs = $('input:text').filter(function(){
        this.id.indexOf("txtSortOrder") !== -1;
    });

    for (i = 0; i <= textboxs.length; i++) {
        $('input:text:eq(' + i + ')').val(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 
 like this solution because it has the filter. With the filter it keeps the order in sync. However I think there might be a small issue with the code because it did not work for me.